# Read socket string java

Tags: java, eclipse

i get 
`<CreateRoom Name='room nam' Mode='2v2/single' Players='4/10'/>` as a TCP socket call and i want to parse and get the tags. I solved it with `strip, replace and startsWith`
But is there a easier way or a correct way to extract the tags?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can regard it as **XML** and use frameworks such as **[dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/)** to parse it.